# brew install emac, it's emacs25, but I want to install emacs24

Tags: macos, emacs, homebrew

#brew install emacs
  The version is emacs25,
  but I want to install emacs24

```
brew install emacs
```

#brew doctor is OK, and macOS10.12

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula

Comment: @brian oh,thx U